# How to display text at the top a cell

Tags: pandas

I see that text can be aligned to the left or to the right.

There are situations where one column has a lot of text and then all other columns have their values in the vertical middle of the column.

`df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'right'})`

I tried

`df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'top'})`

And it didn't work

It seems that this is borrowed from css so I also tried

`df.style.set_properties(**{'vertical-align': 'top'})`

Comment: Hi, `df.style.set_properties(**{'vertical-align': 'top'})` has the desired effect when I run it (pandas 1.4.2, jupyterlab 3.3.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS pairing you want is: `"vertical-align": "text-top"`

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

d = {'A': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'B': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'C': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'D': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 
     'E': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'F': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'G': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 'H': [1, "This is a medium long value"], 
     'X': [1, "This is a really really really long value that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on."]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.style.set_properties(**{"vertical-align": "text-top"})
```

Without `"vertical-align": "text-top"`:

[image: data not aligned]

With `"vertical-align": "text-top"`

[image: data aligned]